# Get a selected Row of DataGridView as a DataRow

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

I have a datagridview that filled by a DataTable's Data; I want to get DataGridView's current selected row and pass this row as a DataRow to another form in `dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick` Event of my DataGridView.
I tried this code:

```
int rw = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
DataRow PassingSessionInfo;
PassingSessionInfo = SessionsData.NewRow();
PassingSessionInfo = dataGridView1.Rows[rw];
```

and `SessionsInfo` is a DataTable.
I Got error, could you please help me?

Comment: Please mention from which DGV do you want to pass DataRow to which DGV, Also mention error which is currently you are getting.

Comment: I want to copy a datagridview Row to a DataRow variable;

Comment: Ok, Try my suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int rw = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
DataRow PassingSessionInfo;
PassingSessionInfo = ((dataGridView1.DataSource) as DataTable).Rows[rw];
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease Try

```
int rw = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
DataRow PassingSessionInfo;
PassingSessionInfo = SessionsData.NewRow();

DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
dt.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[rw]);

PassingSessionInfo = dt.Rows[0];
```

Comment: i wanna copy a Row from DataGridView to a DataRow variable, your code copies all DatGrid's rows to a DataTable

Comment: i Got This Error Message : Input Array is longer than the number of columns inthis table